# Cannot understand the error msg: 'nonstatic member reference must be relative to specific object'

Tags: c++

I Keep getting the 'nonstatic member reference must be relative to specific object' error
and i don't actually get it 
my code is simply Consists of 2 classes :
1-Info
2-Employee

and Employee class inherit from Info

the INFO class has 2 variable : ID - Name.
and I'm trying to access the ID variable like this

```
cin >> Employee.Info.ID
```

any help?

Comment: That's a descriptive title...

Comment: But anyway, try harder. The error message is quite clear. (non-static) member variables are variables within an instance, not within a class.

Comment: have you instantiated an actual object? Employee e; e.ID

Comment: Employee inherits from Info; this does **not** mean that Info is a member of Employee. Try `Employee.ID`

Comment: Each object has its own ID. This makes no sense.

Comment: @trojansdestroy, Better yet, use composition instead of inheritance.

Comment: @chris Just trying to make OP's code work, but you're right about that. Try it out, Mohab. [Composition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance): make an Info object that *is* a member of Employee, then access it just like your original code did. If that still results in error, then you didn't instantiate an object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message clearly states that you are trying to access an object's member without an object: You need to distinguish classes and objects. A `class` defines how objects of that particular `class` look like, i.e., what data members and function members the objects support. You probably want to do something along the lines of

```
Employee worker;
worker.Info.ID = "ID";
std::cout << worker.Info.ID << '\n';
```

(assuming `Info` happens to be a data member of `Employee` whose type in turn has an `ID` data member.

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't supply any code, I am going to write my own. Your classes should look something like this.

```
class ID {
     public:
         string name;
         string ID;
};

class Employee : ID {};

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
     cin >> Employee.Info.ID;
}
```

There are alot of things wrong with the line:

```
cin >> Employee.Info.ID;
```

First of all Employee *extends* Info. It is not a member of Info. This means that all the members of Info become members of Employee. So the code would change to:

```
cin >> Employee.ID;
```

But there is still something wrong with this code. ID is an instance variable. Employee is not an instance it is a class. I am not entire sure what you want to do but there are two ways to fix this: 1) make ID a static variable or 2) create an instance of Employee.

1)

```
class ID {
     public:
         string name;
         static string ID; // Change to static
};
```

2)

```
 int main(int argc, char **argv) {
     Employee my_employee; // Create instance
     cin >> my_employee.ID;
```

What 1) does is set the ID's of *all* employers to the first word in cin. What 2) does is set the ID of my_employee (the instance we created) only.

Comment: You have extra parentheses on `//Create instance`.

Comment: @chris Thanks for pointing it out. Edited it. My C++ isn't up to standard.